# Changing image on dropdown javascript/jquery, working in fiddle, but not elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The life of me cannot get this to work. I'm trying to display an different image as one changes the dropdown menu. It doesn't ever change, that's the issue.

I figure I need to do something with docready, but not sure what!

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var pictureList = [
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/4",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5", ];

    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#picDD').change(function () {
        var val = parseInt($('#picDD').val());
        $('img').attr("src",pictureList[val]);
    });
});

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" />
    <select id="picDD">
        <option value="1" selected>Picute 1</option>
        <option value="2">Picute 2</option>
        <option value="3">Picute 3</option>
        <option value="4">Picute 4</option>
        <option value="5">Picute 5</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Tried this.

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
     var pictureList = [
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/4",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5", ];


    $('#picDD').change(function () {
        var val = parseInt($('#picDD').val());
        $('img').attr("src",pictureList[val]);
    });
});

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" />
    <select id="picDD">
        <option value="1" selected>Picute 1</option>
        <option value="2">Picute 2</option>
        <option value="3">Picute 3</option>
        <option value="4">Picute 4</option>
        <option value="5">Picute 5</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any luck with the code in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is working in jsFiddle is that jsFiddle adds an implicit `onLoad` wrapper to your JavaScript.

[image]

Without that wrapper, you're in trouble. To fix this, move your `pictureList` array inside of `$( document ).ready(function() {}`.

In the jsFiddle demo, I'm also seeing a mixed content warning, because the images you're requesting are coming from an insecure server, though the web page itself is secure (https). If you change the `pictureList` array to contain secure images, the speed improves dramatically. For example, try using this for your `pictureList` array.

```
  var pictureList = [
    "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg",
    "https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/140272627-grooming-needs-senior-cat-632x475.jpg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Cat_March_2010-1.jpg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Large_Siamese_cat_tosses_a_mouse.jpg",
    "https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/cat-black-superstitious-fcs-cat-myths-162286659.jpg"
  ];
```

Comment: I've updated what I have and still doesn't work. I moved the pictureList inside the document ready.

Comment: Thanks very much. :)

Comment: So, the code *is* working, but there are some issues with the served images. The server is secure (https) but the images you're serving are coming from an insecure server. This causes a mixed content warning and really slows things down. You should serve these images from a secure server.

Comment: I updated my answer to include an alternate `pictureList` using secure images.